# html5 canvas drawing becomes jagged on tablet

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Here is my Code:

```
var can = $('#signature')[0],
    ctx = can.getContext('2d'),
    mousePressed = false,
    mouseX = 0,
    mouseY = 0;
can.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove, false);
can.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart, false);
can.addEventListener('touchend', onMouseUp, false);
// Tablet
function onTouchMove(event){
    if (mousePressed) {
        event.preventDefault();
        mouseX = (event.targetTouches[0].pageX) - can.offsetLeft;
        mouseY = (event.targetTouches[0].pageY) - can.offsetTop;
        ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

function onTouchStart(event){
    mousePressed = true;
    mouseX = (event.targetTouches[0].pageX) - can.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = (event.targetTouches[0].pageY) - can.offsetTop;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(mouesX, mouseY);
}

function onMouseUp(event){
    mousePressed = false;
}
// Desktop
can.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
can.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
can.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);

function onMouseMove(event) {
    if (mousePressed) {
        event.preventDefault();
        mouseX = event.clientX - can.offsetLeft;
        mouseY = event.clientY - can.offsetTop;
        ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

function onMouseDown(event) {
    mousePressed = true;
    mouseX = event.clientX - can.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = event.clientY - can.offsetTop;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
}

$('#clearsig')[0].addEventListener('click', clearSignature, false);

function clearSignature() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
}
```

The HTML:

```
<canvas id="signature" width="800" height="350" style="border:1px solid #000;"></canvas>
```

On the desktop everything draws fine with the mouse and I have no problems. However on my galaxy tab 3 When I go to draw on the canvas the line draws a zig zag pattern. No idea why this is happening or how to fix it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KUaEF/ Test this on your tablet, if it works fine, something else on your page is interfering with the canvas. The fiddle works perfectly on my iOS device

Comment: Are you using some CSS styling with your canvas element (besides from the inline)?

Comment: Just the border in the style element @Ken-AbdiasSoftware

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you've found an answer for this but I had a similar issue and finally managed to solve it. Drawing lines on canvas on galaxy tab 2 and 3, also galaxy note 10.1(2012 edition, no problem on 2014 edition) can create jagged lines. Same applies for Izzey's jsfiddle. If your issue is the same as mine then the device is picking both mousemove and touchmove.. It basically draws the line twice with messed up mousemove values. Have a look at this http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/javascript-touch-event-or-mouse-event-detect-and-handle-according-to-device/
It worked for me. I really hope this helps.. :)

Comment: When giving a link answer - always keep in mind that the link can stop working at some point. So try to make sure that your answer contains all the information from the link, even if summarized. It's ok to direct the OP for further reading - but the answer should remain valid even without the link - while your's doesn't look like it is.